# BeautifulSoup - Highlight the anchor text within other text

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

Here is an example of what I have:

`<text>This sign is <a href="http://XXXX"> select color </a> in color <text>`

Here is how I would like to extract the text:

This sign is **select color** in color

I am using Beautiful Soup. Here is what I am doing.

text = soup.find_all('text')

```
for t in text:

   print t.get_text()
```

I get: This sign is select color in color

Is it possible to highlight/bold/Italicize the text within the anchor tags? (This sign is **select color** in color)

Comment: are you just looking to change all hyperlink tags (`<a>`) into bold tags (`<b>`)?

Comment: If that's the case, you might try grabbing each line using BeautifulSoup and then using regex (`import re`) to replace the hyperlink tags with bold tags.

Comment: do you want to just print it in "bold" on terminal ?

Comment: @Bijoy yes I need to print it in bold

Comment: @Chris and Kyle, I need it to appear in bold when I print.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `wrap` and `unwrap`

**Demo:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
s = """<text>This sign is <a href="http://XXXX"> select color </a> in color <text>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(s, "html.parser")
for t in soup.find_all('text'):
    if t.a:
        t.a.wrap(soup.new_tag("b")).find("a").unwrap()
        print(t)
```

**Output:**

```
<text>This sign is <b> select color </b> in color <text></text></text>
```

- **[wrap](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#wrap)**
- **[unwrap](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#unwrap)**

Comment: Thanks @Rakesh. I tried wrap and unwrap. When I use get_text(), I just get the text, 'select color' is not in bold.

Comment: `get_text()` will only get you the text ignoring the tags. https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text